# Is there a way to Invalidate / Cache restart from terminal?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I was wondering if there was any command from terminal that I could use to match the use in Android Studio of doing file>invalidate cache/restart.

Thanks!

Comment: to load bundler with reset cache: `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 4):

[According to a JetBrains employee](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000011850-Automate-Invalid-Caches-Restart-?page=1#community_comment_360000020364) doing the following will have the same effect:

1. Shut down Android Studio externally (using `kill` or similar command), then
2. Delete `system/caches` directory (more on that later), and
3. Start the IDE again.

---

###### How to find `system/caches` directory?

> Location of the IDE files depends on the operating system, product and version.

- For **IntelliJ IDEA** follow [this guide](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519).

  *So e.g. for `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3` on macOS you should be looking for `~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/caches` directory*
- For **Android Studio** follow the same guide as above but instead of `JetBrains` in the path use `Google`

  *So e.g. for `Android Studio 4.2` on macOS you should be looking for `~/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/caches` directory*