# Android Studio - How to invalidate cache from command line?

Tags: android, android-studio, freeze

My Android Studio freezes on startup and I'm unable to get to the "Invalidate Caches and Restart" in the menu.

Is there a way I can do this from the command line instead?

Comment: Here's an answer from JetBrains: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922253/is-there-a-way-to-invalidate-cache-restart-from-terminal